# How do you display the relationships that connect ClassA to ClassX using NDepend?

Tags: dependencies, ndepend, cqlinq

**BACKGROUND**

When driving through an unknown city, it is often preferable to have a map that can help guide you to your destination.  Similarly, when looking at legacy code for the first time it is often preferable to have a diagram that can outline relationships within the application.

**EXAMPLE**

In this case, I have been asked to look at a legacy {data-centric} application to better understand how it manages it's database connections.  Or more specifically, I am trying to generate a class diagram that outlines the relationships between `Program` and `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`.

**THE PROBLEM**

I am relatively new to NDepend, and am having difficulty writing the appropriate CQLinq statement.  Unfortunately, the following only displays assemblies and their relationships to each other.  How would I modify this query to *display the relationships between two types?*

Any insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

```
from t in Assemblies
where t.DepthOfIsUsedBy("MyCompany.MyProject.MyNamespace.Program") >=0 &&
t.DepthOfIsUsing("System.Data.Common.DbConnection") >=0
select new { t, t.NbLinesOfCode}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from t in Assemblies` means that t is an assembly.

You should try `from t in Application.Types`:

```
// <Name>Display relationships between two types</Name>
from t in Application.Types
where t.DepthOfIsUsedBy("Company.Project.NamespaceA") >=0 &&
t.DepthOfIsUsing("Company.Project.NamespaceZ") >=0
select new { t, t.NbLinesOfCode}
```